# position relative css tricks

Tags: css, css-position

I am a new web designer so I decided to analysis other **HTML,CSS** codes. I found a weird thing. Why should some developers use ***position: relative*** without any **top,left,right,bottom**?

Is there any hack or trick in it?

**like this:**

```
.main {
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position `relative` is useful because elements with a position set (thats not `static`) can be used to position other elements inside it. Because `relative` maintains things in the flow of the page, there is no need to set `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` values. If, for example, you want to use `absolute` positioning *inside a box*, you give the outer box `position: relative`. This means any element *inside* it will take its positioning from the top left of the relative outer box. If the parent element does not have positioning set (or inherited), it will position itself to the `viewport` instead of a box. So an element that is not wrapped in a `relative` wrapper will position itself based on the page, while a `relative` wrapper means it will position *relative to* the wrapper.

So thats the hack and thats why you will see it often. **In short**: 'relative' keeps that element in the flow, while children with other positioning will now be positioned relative to this element.

### Quick Example

```css
h1 { width: 100%; }
#relative { position: relative; width: 100%; }
.position { position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; border: 1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<h1>Example:</h1>
<div id="absolute" class="position">Position based on page</div>
<div id="relative"><div class="position">Position based on box</div></div>
```

Comment: thanks, it is reasonable ;)

Comment: @Happy I was working on a quick example as well, so now you know (:

Comment: see this fiddle for an example : https://jsfiddle.net/Lu33Ldjq/

Answer (score 0):

Because relative means that .main inherits from his father node's properties. So it will have the same properties of his father.

Comment: relative means relate to actual place not his father

Answer (score 0):

What it really means is "relative to itself". If you set `position: relative;` on an element but no other positioning attributes (top, left, bottom or right), it will no effect on it's positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as position: static;

But if you give it some other positioning attribute, say, top: 10px;, it will shift it's position 10 pixels DOWN from where it would NORMALLY be.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an HTML element to be `position: relative;` without any pixel-specific direction rules allows you to control the z-axis of the element, making it possible to control the layering of elements on your web page.